# Maxmind .MMDB to .DAT? mod_maxminddb in Debian Repo?

Tags: apache, debian, geoip, maxmind

There is allready another Thread about this which isn't really answered:

[How to Convert a Maxmind .MMDB to .DAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050456/how-to-convert-a-maxmind-mmdb-to-dat)

Here Greg Oschwald, working at Maxmind, said that "The Legacy GeoIP builds (.dat) are not going away in the near future". Yeah, but the future is now, and they are going away on 1. April 2018 which is in a month ;) I really liked my current Apache-Configuration (Debian) using mod_geoip2 and GeoIP .dat-Databases. Works like a charm. So it's kind of anoying to change everything now. Especialy because there is no native Apache-Module like mod-geoip2 to use, but I have to build a module from source, install libraries and mess with my whole apache-config to enable apxs. And I don't have an automatic Update of the new module by repository but have to update it manually with new libraries and new tarballs when they are available. This is not very convenient.

Well, I could download the CSV-release, Add the IP-Ranges with Maxminds provided CSV-Converter (https://github.com/maxmind/geoip2-csv-converter/releases) write a script which transforms the bunch of csv-Files into a single "Legacy-Like" csv-File and transform this with the Debian Program (https://github.com/dankamongmen/sprezzos-world/blob/master/packaging/geoip/debian/src/geoip-csv-to-dat.cpp) to a .dat File. >Maybe< this could work for some time. But it's very ugly. Isn't there a better solution?

If not: Will there be a native Apache Module in the Debian Repository which removes the "build/install it yourself" part? Then I would have no issue with the new format.

Greetings daily